# Differentiate between blank form and 0 using php for html5 form handling

Tags: php, html, forms

```
if(isset($_POST['n']) ){
    $n  = $_POST['n'];
    if(!empty($n) || $n==0){
        echo "n is any number including 0 but not blank";
    }
}
```

How do I check if the form values are blank but can be 0 ? isset($_POST['$var']) is returning true even if the html form is blank. I tried doing the above code but it still isnt working. I can't seem to find a way to separate a blank form and 0.

Comment: What about using `!empty()` or `trim()` ?

Comment: `empty()` returns `true` for 0.  Try `!=''`

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes and thanks. I forgot PHP will evaluate 0 as false and `empty()` will return true for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text inputs are considered successfull even if they are empty so don't use `isset()`. An empty string and 0 are both `empty()` so don't use it here.  Try checking for an empty string:

```
($_POST['n'] != '')
```

Or since you are expecting numbers look at [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php).

Comment: Thanks! The other answer worked as well, but this one was a bit shorter.